# how to add individual/related list to alphabetical order gridview?

Tags: android, listview, android-gridview

can anyone tell me that how to add list items to grid view..for example..i have grid view like A..Z letters.
.suppose if i click on letter A that should go to another layout and show display A content[i.e a related list] and also
 if i click on B letter of grid view that should display b related list in another lay out and soon buttons click..
i hope you got my requirement.can you please tell me how can i do that..
hope you replay me.

for example::
i have a list gird view like this
[A B C D
 E F G H
........
.......Z]
my require answer is:
if we click on letter A that should display like this
A[pressed]then
Abhay
Ajay
Arun
if B letter pressed then
B[pressed]
Brahmaiah
bharth
bhargav.
like above i want to display grid view.please help me in that

```
GridViewActivity.java

GridView gridView;

static final String[] numbers = new String[]{
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
        "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
        "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
        "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = null;
            intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}
....
this is my activity class ..i want to add related content to every letter present in the list.
...

Comment: can you show an example of what you want to acheive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridViewActivity.java

```
    public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

        GridView gridView;

        static final String[] numbers = new String[] { 
                "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
                "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
                "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
                "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
                "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

            gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                   Intent intent = null;
                   intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListActivity.class);
                   // Send the position to the next activity
                   // i.e. position 0 -> numbers[0] -> "A"
                   intent.putExtra("PositionToList", position);
                   startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        }

    }
```

ListActivity.java

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    // Dummy array, Only for example purposes!!! 
    // In real life you will fetch data from somewhere else (i.e. DB, file, resources, network)
    static final String[][] list = new String[][] { 
                {"Abhay", "Ajay", "Arun"},
                {"Brahmaiah", "bharth", "bhargav"},
                ....,
                ....,
                ....};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get the position in order to know the data to be displayed
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = intent.getIntExtra("PositionToList", 0); // here 0 is the default value

        // Set the content to display in your adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list[position]);
        ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Important**
The real point to show here is not the code itself (I didn't check if it compiles btw) but the idea of how to communicate with other activities.

1. First, you want to select something in your GridActivity and then based on that selection you want to display the proper content in your next Activity. This is accomplished using **Intents**.
2. Second, based on the information passed by the previous activity you take decisions in your ListActivity about what and how to display the content.

Comment: thank you very much.it's working.i will keep those instructions in my mind.

Comment: Glad to hear this information was helpful, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: yes it is..but i had another requirement please go through it and help again.that is how to add icon list view to grid view?hope you help me agin

Comment: Hi I assume you're new in Stackoverflow so before requesting more help in this way I suggest to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Also I want to avoid you down votes in the future so before asking for a specific solution for your requirement you should show some of your code trying to solve that problem even if there are errors on it. This is the best way to learn. Also if you're new to Android development read the trainings here http://developer.android.com/training/index.html and the API guides here http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html